# How do I get the player to collide with another object to use as a boundary?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, rigidbody, collider

I'm trying to make a simple game where you move a sphere from left/right and try to avoid falling cubes. If a cube touches the player (sphere), the player dies. I'm trying to set up boundaries using a cylinder with a collider, but every time I hit the collider boundary, the player disappears like they would if they hit a cube. Here is my player script:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
public float moveSpeed = 1;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    transform.position += new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, 0, 0);
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

To make the if condition apply to both lines, put braces around them like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Note: get in the habit of ***always*** using braces with if-, while-, and for-statements to make it explicitly clear what lines the statement applies to.

Comment: I put in the code and the boundary works, but now the player doesn't disappear when the cube hits it

Comment: Does the cube still disappear? And please show your updated code.

Comment: No, I need the sphere to disappear, not the cubes.

Comment: I assumed that collison.gameObject refers to the Cube object, and gameObject refers to the player object (i.e. this script is on the player). Is that correct? Is the problem that `Destroy(gameObject)` is not destroying the player/sphere? But can you confirm that   `Destroy(collision.gameObject)` is still destroying the Cube?

Comment: The cubes aren't supposed to get destroyed, the only thing I want to get destroyed is the player, which is the sphere

Comment: Okay. You have two Destroy calls, but it sounds like you only want one of those...

Comment: Make sure that the Cube's GameObject has the "Cube" tag set properly, and that it has a Collider (set to Trigger?). To help in debugging, you might add Debug.Log() statements both inside and outside the if-statement. See if that code is even called and if it is called, does it get into the if-statement.